# How to call .cmd file as administrator?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

Please let me know how to call .cmd file as administrator from PowerShell script:

1. The second line below should open as Administrator from a PowerShell script:

   ```
   Set-Location "C:\client\service"
   Invoke-Item  "C:\client\service\_install.cmd"
   ```
2. Then the command prompt should wait after execution. This needs to handle in PowerShell script not possible to write in `_install.cmd` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Batch-scripts runs in CMD.exe, so you need to start a CMD.exe process as admin.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/k","C:\client\service\_install.cmd" -Verb RunAs -Wait
```

- `Start-Process` is the cmdlet to start a process
- `-FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"` starts cmd.exe process
- `-ArgumentList "/k","C:\client\service\_install.cmd"` tells `cmd` to leave the console open after running the script (is this what you wanted? if not, replace with `/c` so the cmd-window will close when done). The second argument is your script.
- `-Verb RunAs` tells `Start-Process` to start the process as admin (you will recieve a UAC-window if enabled)
- `-Wait` tells `Start-Process` to wait until the process is finished. With `cmd /k` this means after you exited the command prompt. If you've changed that to `cmd /c`, then it waits until the script is done.

If you need to change the working directory inside the cmd-file, then you need to modify the .cmd, or write a wrapper-script, like:

```
@echo off

cd /d C:\client\service

C:\client\service\_install.cmd
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If you consider this the correct answer (it solved your problem), remember to mark it as answer by clicking the checkbox. :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit @AnsgarWiechers. Small, but horrible typo. :)